# How to add HasReadLink to OData entity?

Tags: asp.net-core, odata

In OData when an entity had a media type, we should return along with the entity:

> "odata.mediaReadLink": "Employees(1)/$value"
>
> "odata.mediaContentType": "image/jpeg",

ref: http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-json-format/v4.0/cs01/odata-json-format-v4.0-cs01.html

I am using aspnet core and OData, but I cannot find the way to do this, well, at least not simply as I would expect this to be.

Below I show how I create the model builder, I add media type to the entity Assessment and then I try to specify the HasReadLink, but when I get an entity by Id, I do not receive back the odata media read link.

```cs
var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder(serviceProvider);

//This adds HasStream true in the metadata
var assessmentEntityType = builder.EntityType<Assessment>();
assessmentEntityType.MediaType();

var assessmentEntitySetConfiguration = builder.EntitySet<Assessment>(nameof(Assessment) + "s");

// Does not produce effects getting the entity by id
// UPDATE: this code below does have effect only if i set false in the second
// parameter, but anyway this has nothing to do with the media read link
assessmentEntitySetConfiguration.HasReadLink(c =>
    {
        return new Uri("/not-shown");
    }, true);

// see NavigationSourceLinkBuilderAnnotation
// https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/d02bc61ea7b31ada1e54abbeebbecb3c5df0e3ac/src/Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Shared/Builder/NavigationSourceLinkBuilderAnnotation.cs

assessmentEntitySetConfiguration.EntityType
    .Filter(QueryOptionSetting.Allowed, nameof(Assessment.IsDeleted))
    .Filter(QueryOptionSetting.Disabled, nameof(Assessment.Description));
```

What am I missing?
I could not find an online example to do this in aspnet core, I found some old example to do it in net framework but it is hacky.

UPDATE 1:
In the OData for .net Framework I used *SetHasDefaultStream* to achieve this.
example:

```
var model = modelBuilder.GetEdmModel();
var answerTypeName = typeof(Answer).FullName;
var answerType = (IEdmEntityType) model.FindDeclaredType(answerTypeName);
model.SetHasDefaultStream(answerType, true);
```

In the new core I don't have an option to set the default stream.

I asked the same on OData.net Github project: https://github.com/OData/odata.net/issues/1555